# If A $\subset$ X and B $\subset$ Y , then (A $\times$ B) $\subset$ (X $\times$ Y)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem is:
If A  $\subset$ X and B $\subset$ Y , then (A $\times$ B) $\subset$ (X $\times$ Y) , and (provided A $\times$ B $\neq$ $\emptyset$) the converse is also true.

I understand the initial statement that (A $\times$ B) $\subset$ (X $\times$ Y) is true because both A and B are subsets of X and Y respectively. Im assuming that the converse would be (X $\times$ Y) $\subset$ (A $\times$ B) if this is the case then doesn't A=X and B=Y instead of subsets?

Comment: No. The converse is$$A\times B\subset X\times Y\implies A\subset X\wedge B\subset Y.$$

Comment: I expect you could find a proof of the converse somewhere on this site if you wanted to.

Comment: No. The "converse" is about tre statement. That is, the proving the converse is proving that if $A\times B\subset  X\times  Y$ then $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what is meant by "the converse is also true" exactly.

[Edit: As mentioned in the comments by the "converse" is meant, that $A\times B\subseteq X\times Y$ implies $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$.]

For a proof of the statement:

Let $(a,b)\in A\times B$. Then $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Since $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ it is $a\in X$ and $b\in Y$. Thus $(a,b)\in X\times Y$.